# MySQL: Multivalued field vs new table

Tags: mysql

What are the advantages and disadvantages of multivalued field vs new relation table?

Lets say a table with the name of the owner and what type of dogs the owner has

```
Owner Table
id     name    dogs
1      Jack    3,4,7

Dog Table
id    name
1     Poodle
2     Labrador
3     ....
```

To find out what jack has, I would probably split by ',' with a server side language on the dogs field and retrieve each id from the dog table.

What if i use a new relation table:

```
Owner Dog Table
owner_id      dog_id
1             3
1             4
1             7
```

The books that I read should avoid multivalued field but when I test the performance, multivalued field is faster. Other than the benefit of foreign key constraint and the ease of manipulation with mysql itself (without server side script to decode that), why should I still use the relation table? Does the performance difference not matter much even on large data?

Comment: Multivalued field advantages: zero. The performance will be faster with another table if you use more than just a few records. With large data multivalued columns are super SLOW and you can't use indexes on them

Comment: How is large data multivalued columns being super slow? You just need to get the multivalued field, split the string by the delimiter, for each id get it from the other table.

Comment: Like I said: No indexes can be used. You need to split the values and indexes are useless then. And you need indexes on large data.

Comment: Think if you ever need the most popular dog

Answer (score 0):

multi-valued fields are a great lazy way of creating relationchips. but it's more recommended to use 3 tables because of the queries you want to make for them. it's a lot easier to make queries for 3 tables than it is for multi-valued fields.

it's all perfectly described at [this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/07/18/multivalued_datatypes_access/?page=1) site.